# Crontab a command with password input automatically

Tags: bash

I'd like to sync the repository with remote regularly with crontab

```
greedy@algorithms:~$ rsync -av root@me.com:/root/books .
root@me.com's password:
```

The above command need to have password input which cause it impossible to set a timely crontab

How could I input the password automatically without artificial intervening.

Comment: Best bet in this case is to set up ssh keys so that you can log in without entering a password.

Comment: great, could you please transmit the comment to answer. @DougO'Neal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set up your account to be able to ssh to `root@me.com` without a password by using ssh keys. Many, many sources on how to to this are available via a web search.